# Send a message from a mac to a pc over the local network

Tags: macos, windows-10, ssh, notify-osd

So this one's been annoying me for some time now. I have a PC (windows 10) and the rest of my family has macs (ranging from Yosemite to el capitan). We're often in different rooms wearing headphones and want to call to each other. However, we can't hear each other if we're wearing headphones, and it's annoying to walk all the way to the other room just for a one sentence question.

My solution was to SSH in to their computers (using bash on windows), install terminal notifier and execute a quick command `terminal-notifier -message "Hey, take off your headphones"` which displays a small popup on their screen. I want to find some equivalent for them to do. Requirements:

- Preferably it would be natively supported. If an installation is needed, it should be lightweight and only need installed on the host (my windows machine)
- My family is relatively non-techy, so they should be able to execute it fairly easily. Maybe some sort of .sh script they can just click on and have it do all the work.
- I've got an always-on linux machine on the network that I'm willing to install anything on. If it makes for an easier (read user friendly) solution, We can tell the mac to communicate with the linux machine which then talks to my machine.